# Where to start with a STM32F4DISCOVERY

Tags: microcontroller

And, I honestly have no clue as to where to start. I've gotten about as far as downloading and installing CodeSourcery Lite...and that's about it.

I'm comfortable with C, I'm comfortable with vim, couldn't do a make file if my life depending on it. Most of my C projects have been small enough to not really require build scripts, which is probably the key reason I haven't learned make.

Most of the tutorials that I've googled up are for something different (and I don't know enough to make the changes for what I have) or just not very good.

My goal as of now, is the make the LEDs blink.

I can break it down (I think) into two questions:

1. Where do I find documentation for this thing? I have the example code, but is that it?
2. What exactly ARE the compilation to hex to board steps?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Development_tools

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that CodeSourcery is supported by ST, use a toolchain that is.

Documentation and projects (including IO_Toggle for flashing LEDS) are here:

http://www.st.com/internet/evalboard/product/252419.jsp

You might find the Atollic tools easiest to use. I had the LEDs flashing a few minutes after I received the kit.

ST  has a support forum for that board here:

https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/STM32F4DISCOVERY/AllItems.aspx

Comment: I don't have Windows, which is adding an extra amount of learning curve. I honestly do feel as if once I can get some blinking going on, I should be fine.

Comment: Using a standard compiler anyone can download install anywhere without worry about code size limits, licensing code requests, or expirations has a LOT to recommend it, even if the chip vendor isn't a fan.  I'm using gcc for the STM32F100 value line devices and am quite happy.  I don't have the particular details for the STM32F4 but would imagine it is generally similar but with a few more extensions.  Look around online and you will probably find someone already has a project skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in the same situation for the developing this for the mac.  Using a virtual machine for windows provides for the easiest set up and use.  If you have to use mac osx the easiest way is to use chibiOS, which is a real time operating system with pre-set-up projects.

I outlined it pretty well in the chibiOS forums here:[Install toolchain for STM32F4DISCOVERY on the MAC](http://forum.chibios.org/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=361)

The basic components that I used were
1 - YAGARTO for the compiler
2 - Eclipse for the IDE
3 - qstlink for uploading the code

I explain how to install all of them in that posting.  Good Luck, I am still working on trying to get the debugging part working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have this one right now:

https://github.com/dwelch67/stm32vld

It is not the stm32F though.  I have two of the stm32F discovery boards on order should be here early next week and I may have more samples on github that day or the day after.

Answer (score -3):

Using Windows7 (x64), Atollic TrueStudio Lite (set up for ease of use).
ST Microelectronics, document [UM1061](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/USER_MANUAL/DM00023896.pdf) has examples of setting up various functions.
But most helpful were [Elia's Electronics Blog](http://eliaselectronics.com/) and [Andrew Markham's examples](http://amarkham.com/?page_id=96) and I just found [stm32f4-examples on Github](https://github.com/k-code/stm32f4-examples).

Best suggestion: start with AVR (Arduino using Atmega328 or similar): very well documented. I built a robotic tank and also an IP controlled tank with that system, although you may be bored using the easy Arduino library (based on C++ but with very easy user interface layer for nonprogrammers such as myself).
However, using AVR Studio or Eclipse or other IDEs you can use pure C, as I have recently done before rising to ARM.

Comment: Most of this is irrelevant to the original question.